# range of a function involving square root

Tags: calculus, analysis

To obtain the range of a given function $y=f(x)$ we isolate $x$ in terms of $y$, that is $x=g(y)$ so the $ranf(x)=domg(y)$ where $g(y)$ is a relation not necessarily a function.

I know that the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{3x-2}$ is $[0,\infty)$. But can I obtain this analytically? If use the above method I do not get the correct result since isolating $x$ we get $x=\frac{y^{2}+2}{3}$ and its domain its $\mathbb{R}$ why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

You did the right maths in calculating the inverse function. But what you need to take into account is that even if the domain of the inverse is the whole $\mathbb{R}$, you have to observe what the domain of the direct function is.

In your case, you have a square root, and square root is not defined in $\mathbb{R}^-$.

This is why the range shall take this into account and your $\mathbb{R}$ has to be limited to where the initial function does exist.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

the domain of your function is $3x-2\ge \Rightarrow x\ge \frac{2}{3} 0$ and for $x$ in this domain the argument of the square root assume all values in $[0,+\infty)$, and remember that $\sqrt{A}$ is ,by definition, the **positive** real number $B$ such that $B^2=A$.

Comment: that is its domain

Comment: @user369393. Than you! My stupid ...! I edit.